# How to auto-shutdown Ubuntu Server 23.04 when inactive/hdd not used

Tags: server, hard-drive, shutdown, schedule

I have a media server with 1 hard drive. I use it daily at evening, so it would be a waste of electricity if the server is turned on 24/7. So, I want to shut it down when it is not in use, automatically.

The solution would be that when Ubuntu detects no hard drive activity on the media hard drive, the server would shut down after about 15 minutes or so. How can I set something like this up?

The server should not check for activity on the startup SSD, but only on the media hdd that contains all the media files.

(Mine is setup with Ubuntu 23.04, docker, cockpit, portainer, jellyfin, rr apps)

Comment: Can you specify latest possible time when you will be using that server? For example, you will not be using the server later than midnight, or later than 1:00 AM? In that case, you can just set up a cron job that will shutdown the server at - say - 1:15 AM. It's not exactly what you ask for, but it will at least shut down your server every night at predefined hour, which will prevent it from running 24/7.

Comment: Already have cronjob shutdown at 2.30 am